# sequentially order by group AND when condition is met in R

Tags: r, grouping

Here is my dataframe:

```
    df <- data.frame(id=c("124", "124", "124", "456", "456", "456", "456", "8675", "8675", "8675", "8675", "8675", "124", "124", "124", "124"), 
            condition=c("beg", "mid", "end", "beg", "mid", "mid", "end", "beg", "mid", "mid", "mid", "end", "beg", "mid", "mid", "end"),
            school=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e", "f", "g", "h", "h", "h", "u", "j", "k", "k", "l"),
            start_date=c("20000105", "20000601", "20000901", "20000105", "20000601", "20000620", "20000901", "19990805", "20000105", "20000601", "20000901", "20010115", "20060105", "20060701", "20061001", "20070110"),
            end_date=c("20000501", "20000801", "20001215", "20000501", "20000801", "20001210", "20001215", "19991213", "20000501", "20000801", "20001215", "20010515", "20060501", "20060915", "20061215", "20070510"))
```

Many of the questions I've seen either order within a group:

```
df_edited <- df  %>% 
         group_by(id, idx = cumsum(seq == 1L)) %>% 
         mutate(counter = row_number()) %>% 
         ungroup %>% 
         select(-idx)
```

or restart at 1 once a condition is made.

```
df_edited$num <- ave(df_edited$id, df_edited$condition, FUN = seq_along)
```

I've marked those as favorites but they're not applicable to what I want to do right now. What I'd like is the group number to be the same by `id` and change after `df$condition=="end"`

```
id      condition   school  start_date  end_date    group
124     beg         a       20000105    20000501    1
124     mid         b       20000601    20000801    1
124     end         c       20000901    20001215    1
456     beg         d       20000105    20000501    2
456     mid         e       20000601    20000801    2
456     mid         e       20000620    20001210    2
456     end         f       20000901    20001215    2
8675    beg         g       19990805    19991213    3
8675    mid         h       20000105    20000501    3
8675    mid         h       20000601    20000801    3
8675    mid         h       20000901    20001215    3
8675    end         h       20010115    20010515    3
124     beg         j       20060105    20060501    4
124     mid         k       20060701    20060915    4
124     mid         k       20061001    20061215    4
124     end         l       20070110    20070510    4
```

Can someone assist? Thank you!

Each ID can go through the beg, mid, end, multiple times but I'd still like the group number to be different even if the ID is the same.

Comment: Isn't this the 'id' as 'group. i.e. `df %>% mutate(group = group_indices(., id))`

Comment: fair question. i'll go back and edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a group index, then use `rleid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
   mutate(group = rleid(id))
#      id condition school start_date end_date group
#1   124       beg      a   20000105 20000501     1
#2   124       mid      b   20000601 20000801     1
#3   124       end      c   20000901 20001215     1
#4   456       beg      d   20000105 20000501     2
#5   456       mid      e   20000601 20000801     2
#6   456       mid      e   20000620 20001210     2
#7   456       end      f   20000901 20001215     2
#8  8675       beg      g   19990805 19991213     3
#9  8675       mid      h   20000105 20000501     3
#10 8675       mid      h   20000601 20000801     3
#11 8675       mid      h   20000901 20001215     3
#12 8675       end      u   20010115 20010515     3
#13  124       beg      j   20060105 20060501     4
#14  124       mid      k   20060701 20060915     4
#15  124       mid      k   20061001 20061215     4
#16  124       end      l   20070110 20070510     4
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df$group <-   with(rle(df$id), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
```

Comment: thank you. you brought up a point i didn't think of so i edited the desired output.

Comment: thank you for your offer. it's still not working so i'll be editing the question

Comment: @tangerine7199 I am getting your expected output.  Please check the output I updated